# Set rate for crowdsale after it has ended

Tags: ico, crowdsale, openzeppelin-contracts

The problem I am trying to solve is how to *properly price an ICO*.

One idea would be to have 10 tokens available.  Do the ICO and collect all the ETH. Then after the ICO has ended, divvy up the tokens according to how much each person paid.

Example 1: There are a 10 tokens.  10 people give 1 ETH each. The sale ends after a day. Each person gets 1 token.

Example 2: There are a 10 tokens.  5 people give 1 ETH each. The sale ends after a day. Each person gets 2 tokens.

I'm trying to minimize the amount of solidity programming.
Is there a way to do this in openzeppelin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...how to properly price an ICO

Use a mechanism that allows for price discovery during the ICO itself. This is in contrast both to the case of setting a static price during the ICO, and the case of the markets deciding the price *after* the ICO, and once the token is being openly traded.

Such crowdsales are, however, more complex to run. (I can't immediately see anything in the relevant [OpenZeppelin repository](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale).)

One implementation is discussed in the paper *[Interactive Coin Offerings](https://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~teutsch/papers/ico.pdf)* [Teutsch, Buterin, Brown]. Here, the "interactivity" basically refers to the ability for investors to remove their investment while the ICO is still running, if they feel the price is too expensive. (The price is presumably dynamic, or described by a curve over time, with the curvature being influenced by the buy/sell behaviour of investors.)

> I'm trying to minimize the amount of solidity programming.

There's an implementation, [here](https://github.com/TrueBitFoundation/interactive-coin-offerings), so you won't have to code the whole thing yourself, though it'd be prudent to spend time understanding the code.